# filter data from ajax responce and insert the final values to <option> tag

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've a ajax response like this-

```
    [
{"id":"16","0":"16","blockNo":"PGPL\/003","1":"PGPL\/003","buyer":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","2":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"320","4":"320","netB":"180","5":"180","netH":"190","6":"190","netCUM":"10.944","7":"10.944","grossL":"325","8":"325","grossB":"185","9":"185","grossH":"195","10":"195","grossCUM":"11.724","11":"11.724","allowance":"5","12":"5","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"15","0":"15","blockNo":"PGPL\/002","1":"PGPL\/002","buyer":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","2":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"330","4":"330","netB":"185","5":"185","netH":"200","6":"200","netCUM":"12.21","7":"12.21","grossL":"340","8":"340","grossB":"195","9":"195","grossH":"210","10":"210","grossCUM":"13.923","11":"13.923","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"14","0":"14","blockNo":"PIL\/008","1":"PIL\/008","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"320","4":"320","netB":"165","5":"165","netH":"190","6":"190","netCUM":"10.032","7":"10.032","grossL":"325","8":"325","grossB":"170","9":"170","grossH":"195","10":"195","grossCUM":"10.774","11":"10.774","allowance":"5","12":"5","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"13","0":"13","blockNo":"PIL\/007","1":"PIL\/007","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"325","4":"325","netB":"155","5":"155","netH":"165","6":"165","netCUM":"8.312","7":"8.312","grossL":"335","8":"335","grossB":"165","9":"165","grossH":"175","10":"175","grossCUM":"9.673","11":"9.673","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"12","0":"12","blockNo":"PIL\/006","1":"PIL\/006","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"285","4":"285","netB":"165","5":"165","netH":"180","6":"180","netCUM":"8.464","7":"8.464","grossL":"295","8":"295","grossB":"175","9":"175","grossH":"190","10":"190","grossCUM":"9.809","11":"9.809","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"11","0":"11","blockNo":"PIL\/005","1":"PIL\/005","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"325","4":"325","netB":"175","5":"175","netH":"195","6":"195","netCUM":"11.091","7":"11.091","grossL":"335","8":"335","grossB":"185","9":"185","grossH":"205","10":"205","grossCUM":"12.705","11":"12.705","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"10","0":"10","blockNo":"PIL\/004","1":"PIL\/004","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"300","4":"300","netB":"180","5":"180","netH":"190","6":"190","netCUM":"10.26","7":"10.26","grossL":"310","8":"310","grossB":"190","9":"190","grossH":"200","10":"200","grossCUM":"11.78","11":"11.78","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"9","0":"9","blockNo":"PIL\/003","1":"PIL\/003","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"315","4":"315","netB":"195","5":"195","netH":"220","6":"220","netCUM":"13.514","7":"13.514","grossL":"320","8":"320","grossB":"200","9":"200","grossH":"225","10":"225","grossCUM":"14.4","11":"14.4","allowance":"5","12":"5","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"8","0":"8","blockNo":"PGPL\/001","1":"PGPL\/001","buyer":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","2":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"340","4":"340","netB":"190","5":"190","netH":"200","6":"200","netCUM":"12.92","7":"12.92","grossL":"350","8":"350","grossB":"200","9":"200","grossH":"210","10":"210","grossCUM":"14.7","11":"14.7","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"7","0":"7","blockNo":"PIL\/002","1":"PIL\/002","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"315","4":"315","netB":"210","5":"210","netH":"220","6":"220","netCUM":"14.553","7":"14.553","grossL":"320","8":"320","grossB":"215","9":"215","grossH":"225","10":"225","grossCUM":"15.48","11":"15.48","allowance":"5","12":"5","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"6","0":"6","blockNo":"PIL\/101","1":"PIL\/101","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"0","4":"0","netB":"0","5":"0","netH":"0","6":"0","netCUM":"0","7":"0","grossL":"0","8":"0","grossB":"0","9":"0","grossH":"0","10":"0","grossCUM":"0","11":"0","allowance":"0","12":"0","udL":"345","13":"345","udB":"190","14":"190","udH":"215","15":"215","udCUM":"14.093","16":"14.093","status1":"1","17":"1","status2":"1","18":"1","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"5","0":"5","blockNo":"PIL\/001","1":"PIL\/001","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"320","4":"320","netB":"180","5":"180","netH":"200","6":"200","netCUM":"11.52","7":"11.52","grossL":"330","8":"330","grossB":"190","9":"190","grossH":"210","10":"210","grossCUM":"13.167","11":"13.167","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"1","17":"1","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""}
]
```

now what i want to do is filter the and get only the entries which have status1 = 0 and then insert the buyer value in  tag without repeating the buyer value with Javascript.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Looks like a homework. Please ask for concepts, not for your personal work. Conceptwise, read about filter, map and reduce functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the final code that worked for me-

```
success:function(answer){           

        var filteredresults = answer.filter(function(answer) {
          return answer.status1=="0" && answer.udL=="0";
        });

        var uniqueBuyers=$.unique(filteredresults.map(function(o){return o.buyer}));

        var uniqueNames = [];
        $.each(uniqueBuyers, function(i, el){
            if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
        });

        $.each(uniqueNames, function(key, value) {   
            $('.selectBuyer')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                            .attr("value",value)
                            .text(value)); 
        });

    }
```

Thanks Negi Rox for the help. And thanks undefined even your code also works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var z=[
{"id":"16","0":"16","blockNo":"PGPL\/003","1":"PGPL\/003","buyer":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","2":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"320","4":"320","netB":"180","5":"180","netH":"190","6":"190","netCUM":"10.944","7":"10.944","grossL":"325","8":"325","grossB":"185","9":"185","grossH":"195","10":"195","grossCUM":"11.724","11":"11.724","allowance":"5","12":"5","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"15","0":"15","blockNo":"PGPL\/002","1":"PGPL\/002","buyer":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","2":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"330","4":"330","netB":"185","5":"185","netH":"200","6":"200","netCUM":"12.21","7":"12.21","grossL":"340","8":"340","grossB":"195","9":"195","grossH":"210","10":"210","grossCUM":"13.923","11":"13.923","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"14","0":"14","blockNo":"PIL\/008","1":"PIL\/008","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"320","4":"320","netB":"165","5":"165","netH":"190","6":"190","netCUM":"10.032","7":"10.032","grossL":"325","8":"325","grossB":"170","9":"170","grossH":"195","10":"195","grossCUM":"10.774","11":"10.774","allowance":"5","12":"5","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"13","0":"13","blockNo":"PIL\/007","1":"PIL\/007","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"325","4":"325","netB":"155","5":"155","netH":"165","6":"165","netCUM":"8.312","7":"8.312","grossL":"335","8":"335","grossB":"165","9":"165","grossH":"175","10":"175","grossCUM":"9.673","11":"9.673","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"12","0":"12","blockNo":"PIL\/006","1":"PIL\/006","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"285","4":"285","netB":"165","5":"165","netH":"180","6":"180","netCUM":"8.464","7":"8.464","grossL":"295","8":"295","grossB":"175","9":"175","grossH":"190","10":"190","grossCUM":"9.809","11":"9.809","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"11","0":"11","blockNo":"PIL\/005","1":"PIL\/005","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"325","4":"325","netB":"175","5":"175","netH":"195","6":"195","netCUM":"11.091","7":"11.091","grossL":"335","8":"335","grossB":"185","9":"185","grossH":"205","10":"205","grossCUM":"12.705","11":"12.705","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"10","0":"10","blockNo":"PIL\/004","1":"PIL\/004","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"300","4":"300","netB":"180","5":"180","netH":"190","6":"190","netCUM":"10.26","7":"10.26","grossL":"310","8":"310","grossB":"190","9":"190","grossH":"200","10":"200","grossCUM":"11.78","11":"11.78","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"9","0":"9","blockNo":"PIL\/003","1":"PIL\/003","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"315","4":"315","netB":"195","5":"195","netH":"220","6":"220","netCUM":"13.514","7":"13.514","grossL":"320","8":"320","grossB":"200","9":"200","grossH":"225","10":"225","grossCUM":"14.4","11":"14.4","allowance":"5","12":"5","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"8","0":"8","blockNo":"PGPL\/001","1":"PGPL\/001","buyer":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","2":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"340","4":"340","netB":"190","5":"190","netH":"200","6":"200","netCUM":"12.92","7":"12.92","grossL":"350","8":"350","grossB":"200","9":"200","grossH":"210","10":"210","grossCUM":"14.7","11":"14.7","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"7","0":"7","blockNo":"PIL\/002","1":"PIL\/002","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"315","4":"315","netB":"210","5":"210","netH":"220","6":"220","netCUM":"14.553","7":"14.553","grossL":"320","8":"320","grossB":"215","9":"215","grossH":"225","10":"225","grossCUM":"15.48","11":"15.48","allowance":"5","12":"5","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"6","0":"6","blockNo":"PIL\/101","1":"PIL\/101","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"0","4":"0","netB":"0","5":"0","netH":"0","6":"0","netCUM":"0","7":"0","grossL":"0","8":"0","grossB":"0","9":"0","grossH":"0","10":"0","grossCUM":"0","11":"0","allowance":"0","12":"0","udL":"345","13":"345","udB":"190","14":"190","udH":"215","15":"215","udCUM":"14.093","16":"14.093","status1":"1","17":"1","status2":"1","18":"1","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"5","0":"5","blockNo":"PIL\/001","1":"PIL\/001","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"320","4":"320","netB":"180","5":"180","netH":"200","6":"200","netCUM":"11.52","7":"11.52","grossL":"330","8":"330","grossB":"190","9":"190","grossH":"210","10":"210","grossCUM":"13.167","11":"13.167","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"1","17":"1","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""}
]

var filteredresults = z.filter(function(z) {
  return z.status1=="0";
});
var uniqueBuyers=$.unique(filteredresults.map(function(o){return o.buyer}));

$.each(uniqueBuyers,function(i,o){
   console.log(o);
   $("#results").append(o +'<br/>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='results'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Negi Rox for the help. Sorry can't upvote because of my reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var response = [
{"id":"16","0":"16","blockNo":"PGPL\/003","1":"PGPL\/003","buyer":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","2":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"320","4":"320","netB":"180","5":"180","netH":"190","6":"190","netCUM":"10.944","7":"10.944","grossL":"325","8":"325","grossB":"185","9":"185","grossH":"195","10":"195","grossCUM":"11.724","11":"11.724","allowance":"5","12":"5","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"15","0":"15","blockNo":"PGPL\/002","1":"PGPL\/002","buyer":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","2":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"330","4":"330","netB":"185","5":"185","netH":"200","6":"200","netCUM":"12.21","7":"12.21","grossL":"340","8":"340","grossB":"195","9":"195","grossH":"210","10":"210","grossCUM":"13.923","11":"13.923","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"14","0":"14","blockNo":"PIL\/008","1":"PIL\/008","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"320","4":"320","netB":"165","5":"165","netH":"190","6":"190","netCUM":"10.032","7":"10.032","grossL":"325","8":"325","grossB":"170","9":"170","grossH":"195","10":"195","grossCUM":"10.774","11":"10.774","allowance":"5","12":"5","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"13","0":"13","blockNo":"PIL\/007","1":"PIL\/007","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"325","4":"325","netB":"155","5":"155","netH":"165","6":"165","netCUM":"8.312","7":"8.312","grossL":"335","8":"335","grossB":"165","9":"165","grossH":"175","10":"175","grossCUM":"9.673","11":"9.673","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"12","0":"12","blockNo":"PIL\/006","1":"PIL\/006","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"285","4":"285","netB":"165","5":"165","netH":"180","6":"180","netCUM":"8.464","7":"8.464","grossL":"295","8":"295","grossB":"175","9":"175","grossH":"190","10":"190","grossCUM":"9.809","11":"9.809","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"11","0":"11","blockNo":"PIL\/005","1":"PIL\/005","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"325","4":"325","netB":"175","5":"175","netH":"195","6":"195","netCUM":"11.091","7":"11.091","grossL":"335","8":"335","grossB":"185","9":"185","grossH":"205","10":"205","grossCUM":"12.705","11":"12.705","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"10","0":"10","blockNo":"PIL\/004","1":"PIL\/004","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"300","4":"300","netB":"180","5":"180","netH":"190","6":"190","netCUM":"10.26","7":"10.26","grossL":"310","8":"310","grossB":"190","9":"190","grossH":"200","10":"200","grossCUM":"11.78","11":"11.78","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"9","0":"9","blockNo":"PIL\/003","1":"PIL\/003","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"315","4":"315","netB":"195","5":"195","netH":"220","6":"220","netCUM":"13.514","7":"13.514","grossL":"320","8":"320","grossB":"200","9":"200","grossH":"225","10":"225","grossCUM":"14.4","11":"14.4","allowance":"5","12":"5","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"8","0":"8","blockNo":"PGPL\/001","1":"PGPL\/001","buyer":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","2":"PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"340","4":"340","netB":"190","5":"190","netH":"200","6":"200","netCUM":"12.92","7":"12.92","grossL":"350","8":"350","grossB":"200","9":"200","grossH":"210","10":"210","grossCUM":"14.7","11":"14.7","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"7","0":"7","blockNo":"PIL\/002","1":"PIL\/002","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"315","4":"315","netB":"210","5":"210","netH":"220","6":"220","netCUM":"14.553","7":"14.553","grossL":"320","8":"320","grossB":"215","9":"215","grossH":"225","10":"225","grossCUM":"15.48","11":"15.48","allowance":"5","12":"5","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"0","17":"0","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"6","0":"6","blockNo":"PIL\/101","1":"PIL\/101","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"0","4":"0","netB":"0","5":"0","netH":"0","6":"0","netCUM":"0","7":"0","grossL":"0","8":"0","grossB":"0","9":"0","grossH":"0","10":"0","grossCUM":"0","11":"0","allowance":"0","12":"0","udL":"345","13":"345","udB":"190","14":"190","udH":"215","15":"215","udCUM":"14.093","16":"14.093","status1":"1","17":"1","status2":"1","18":"1","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""},
{"id":"5","0":"5","blockNo":"PIL\/001","1":"PIL\/001","buyer":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","2":"PELICAN INDIA LTD","user":"Jogesh Ravani","3":"Jogesh Ravani","netL":"320","4":"320","netB":"180","5":"180","netH":"200","6":"200","netCUM":"11.52","7":"11.52","grossL":"330","8":"330","grossB":"190","9":"190","grossH":"210","10":"210","grossCUM":"13.167","11":"13.167","allowance":"10","12":"10","udL":"0","13":"0","udB":"0","14":"0","udH":"0","15":"0","udCUM":"0","16":"0","status1":"1","17":"1","status2":"0","18":"0","rate":"0","19":"0","cost":"0","20":"0","pi":"","21":"","ti":"","22":""}
]

var list = []
var options = response.filter(re => re.status1 == 0).filter(val => list.indexOf(val.buyer) === -1 ? (list.push(val.buyer), true) : false)
console.log(list)
```